# How to optimize the memory and time usage of the following algorithm in python

Tags: python, performance, sorting, memory, networkx

I am trying to accomplish the following logical operation in Python but getting into memory and time issues. Since, I am very new to python, guidance on how and where to optimize the problem would be appreciated ! ( I do understand that the following question is somewhat abstract )

```
import networkx as nx 
    dic_score = {}
    G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(10000,10,.01) # Generate 2 graphs with 10,000 nodes using Networkx
    H = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(10000,10,.01)
    for Gnodes in G.nodes()
        for Hnodes in H.nodes ()  # i.e. For all the pair of nodes in both the graphs
           score = SomeOperation on (Gnodes,Hnodes)  # Calculate a metric 
           dic_score.setdefault(Gnodes,[]).append([Hnodes, score, -1 ]) # Store the metric in the form a Key: value, where value become a list of lists, pair in a dictionary
```

Then Sort the lists in the generated dictionary according to the criterion mentioned here 
[sorting_criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219770/how-to-sort-the-outer-and-inner-sublist-of-a-nested-list-in-python)

My problems/questions are:

1) Is there a better way of approaching this than using the for loops for iteration?

2) What should be the most optimized (fastest) method of approaching the above mentioned problem ? Should I consider using another data structure than a dictionary ? or possibly file operations ?

3) Since I need to sort the lists inside this dictionary, which has 10,000 keys each corresponding to a list of 10,000 values, memory requirements become huge quite quickly and I run out of it.

3) Is there a way to integrate the sorting process within the calculation of dictionary itself i.e. avoid doing a separate loop to sort?

Any inputs would be appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: 10^4 x 10^4 nodes = 10^8. Of course it is slow. Without the information of what you are trying to do, the run time and memory usage is hard to improve.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Basically, the loops stand for extracting a vector associated with each node. I am interested in say the dot product of all possible pairs of these vectors from both the graphs i.e. the 10000*10000 pairs.Therefore every node will get associated with 10000 such dot products which I then want to sort and save for further process. As you correctly mentioned, computational time is huge and so are memory requirements, which I want to optimize, possibly by some file operation or any other suggest that you may have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You can use one of functions from `itertools` module for that. Let me just mention it, you can read the manual or call:

```
from itertools import product
help(product)
```

Here's an example:

```
for item1, item2 in product(list1, list2):
    pass
```

2) If the result is too big to fit in memory, try saving them somewhere. You can output it into a CSV file for example:

```
with open('result.csv') as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel')
   for ...
       writer.write(...)
```

This will free your memory.

3) I think it's better to sort the result data afterwards (because `sort` function is rather quick) rather than complicate the matters and sort the data on the fly.

You could instead use [NumPy](http://numpy.org/) arroy/matrix operations (sums, products, or even map a function to each matrix row). These are so fast that sometimes filtering the data costs more than calculating everything.

If your app is still very slow, try profiling it to see exactly what operation is slow or is done too many times:

```
from cProfile import Profile
p = Profile()

p.runctx('my_function(args)', {'my_function': my_function, 'args': my_data}, {})
p.print_stats()
```

You'll see the table:

```
      2706 function calls (2004 primitive calls) in 4.504 CPU seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     2    0.006    0.003    0.953    0.477 pobject.py:75(save_objects)
  43/3    0.533    0.012    0.749    0.250 pobject.py:99(evaluate)
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Let me work on your feedback and observer the results.

Comment: A NumPy array is also memory efficient.

Answer (score 4):

**When working with functions that returns a list, check out for a function that returns an iterator.**

This will improve memory usage.

In your case, `nx.nodes` returns the complete list. See: [nodes](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.nodes.html#networkx.classes.function.nodes)

**Use `nodes_iter`** since it returns an iterator. This should ensure that you do not have the full list of nodes in memory while iterating on the nodes in your for loop.

See: [nodes_iter](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.nodes_iter.html#networkx.classes.function.nodes_iter)

Some improvement:

```
import networkx as nx 
    dic_score = {}
    G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(10000,10,.01) 
    H = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(10000,10,.01)
    for Gnodes in G.nodes_iter() ----------------> changed from G.nodes()
        for Hnodes in H.nodes_iter()  -----------> changed from H.nodes()
           score = SomeOperation on (Gnodes,Hnodes) 
           dic_score.setdefault(Gnodes,[]).append([Hnodes, score, -1 ])
```

You can also use the other idiom since now you have two iterators: use [itertools.products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034014/in-python-how-to-apply-itertools-product-to-elements-of-a-list-of-lists)

```
product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).
```

Comment: This is really very helpful ! Thanks for the insights. I am trying to implement all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned `itertools.product`. That's good, but in your case, there is another possibility: a generator expression for the inner loop, and the `sorted` function. (Code untested, of course.)

```
import networkx as nx
from operator import itemgetter 
dic_score = {}
G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(10000,10,.01) # Generate 2 graphs with 10,000 nodes using Networkx
H = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(10000,10,.01)
for Gnodes in G.nodes():
    dic_score[Gnodes] = sorted([Hnodes, score(Gnodes, Hnodes), -1] for Hnodes in H.nodes(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) # sort on score
```

The inner loop is replaced by a generator expression. It is also sorted on the fly (assuming you want to sort each inner list on `score`). Instead of storing in a dictionary, you could easily write each inner list to a file, which would help with memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am unsure here as I am learning Python, but have come across a cPickle module. Will using it after each inner loop help my cause in anyway ?

Comment: If memory is your main problem, you can replace `dic_score[Gnodes] = ...` with writing the result to disk. I don't know enough about (c)Pickle to help you with it, but I think it would work.